# Creating hybrid local app in CMD using mobile SDK

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am trying to create hybrid_local app for which 
I have followed the following steps in Windows environment:

1. Installed JDK
2. Installed Android Studio 2
3. Installed Android SDK from Android Studio 2
4. Installed Android Virtual Device (AVD) from within Android Studio
5. Installed Node.js and npm
6. Installed Cordova by command npm -g install cordova

then entered

`forcedroid create` in cmd 
asked for application_type
then entered `hybrid_local` 
cmd prompts with application name but I am not able to enter anything, not sure what's wrong and If I am missing any steps.

Please see the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend typing `forcedroid create` with other arguments listed [in forcedroid page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forcedroid)

for example: `forcedroid create --apptype=hybrid_local --appname=FSMobility --packagename=com.companyname.appname --outputdir=newFolderName`